# Joi validation length number

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, schema, joi

I'm trying to do a length validation on a number, but it doesn't seem to work correctly.
 This is my schema:

```
const schema = createJoiSchema({
  email: Joi.string().required(),
  password: Joi.string().required(),
  phone: Joi.number().integer().min(10).max(10).required(),    
})
```

This is my test object:

```
{
    "email":"miguel@gmail.com",
    "password":"miguel123",
    "phone": 1234456789
}
```

And I get this error:

```
"ValidationError: \"phone\" must be less than or equal to 10.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `min` and `max` on an **integer**, it should actually be between 10^9 (min has 10 digits) and 10^10 - 1 (max has 10 digits):

```js
const schema = createJoiSchema({
  email: Joi.string().required(),
  password: Joi.string().required(),
  phone: Joi.number().integer().min(1000000000).max(9999999999).required(),
})
```

AKA

```js
const schema = createJoiSchema({
  email: Joi.string().required(),
  password: Joi.string().required(),
  phone: Joi.number().integer().min(10**9).max(10**10 - 1).required(),
})
```

Comment: nice try but it will not work with numbers that start with 0

Comment: Numbers that start with 0 are considered as octal, not in decimal: 0777 (base 8) = 511 (base 10)